# truncate output in BASH

Tags: linux, bash

How do I truncate output in BASH?

For example, if I "du file.name" how do I just get the numeric value and nothing more?

later addition:
all solutions work perfectly. I chose to accept the most enlightning "cut" answer because I prefer the simplest approach in bash files others are supposed to be able to read.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you know what the delimiters are then cut is your friend

```
du | cut -f1
```

Cut defaults to tab delimiters so in this case you are selecting the first field.

You can change delimiters: cut -d ' ' would use a space as a delimiter. (from [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak))

You can also select individual character positions or ranges:

```
ls | cut -c1-2
```

Comment: You can add something like "cut -d ' ' -f 1-2", to point out how to change the characters cut uses as delimiters.

Answer (score 10):

I'd recommend cut, as others have said. But another alternative that is sometimes useful because it allows any whitespace as separators, is to use awk:

```
du file.name | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: +1 If the delimiter could be any whitespace, then awk is the most robust solution (even if it's not as pretty as using cut).

Answer (score 6):

```
du | cut -f 1
```

Comment: beat me to it by 20 seconds :)

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds :) I've deleted my duplicate answer and added an alternative answer instead.

Comment: I'd prefer more information about delimiters and ranges since he was only using du as an example. Then I'll happily delete too :)

Comment: Can I just copy yours or do I have to invent my own? :-)

Comment: Please just copy if you think they are ok - if not invent your own

Comment: I've no idea what the etiquette is here - if you want to add the detail to yours I can presumably still just delete?

Comment: Don't bother. My answer was faster, yours was more complete. So yours has been rightfully accepted, that's how this site works. I've got my share of up-votes. :-D

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the number of bytes of a single file, use the `-s` operator.

```
SIZE=-s file.name
```

That gives you a different number than `du`, but I'm not sure how exactly you're using this.

This has the advantage of not having to run `du`, and having `bash` get the size of the file directly.

It's hard to answer questions like this in a vacuum, because we don't know how you're going to use the data.  Knowing that might suggest an entirely different answer.

Comment: In the original question he said that using du was just an example; your answer doesn't help with his question (although it may in fact be useful to him if his example wasn't just hypothetical)

Comment: Yes, I read that.  And I didn't interpret it as "du was just an example."

Comment: I don't understand how this is used. What's the context?

Comment: Please explain "If you just want the number of bytes of a single file, use the -s operator." If I type that at a Bash prompt, I get a "file.name: command not found" error (for a file that exists with that name). How do I make the `-s` operator work? The only one I know of is for the conditional expression to test whether a file exists and is not empty: `[[ -s file.name ]] && echo "yes"` for example, but that doesn't tell me the actual size.